# Take average of an attribute from 1 table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables named product and review. Product table has the following columns -

prod_name(primary key), xyz, rating

And Review table has the columns -

prod_name, username, rating, review

Now whenever a user enters a review and rating, it is added in the review table. I want the average of the rating for that particular product to be updated in product table's rating column.

Example - in product table there is a product "x" and that product has been given a rating 7,8,6 by three users "a","b","c" respectively. and i want the ratings attribute of "x" to be updated to 7 as soon as the three ratings are given.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: you can do it manually after add data in review table than update the prod_name table. Or you can use trigger

Comment: What happens when user d rates the same product?

Answer (score 0):

**onclick** event of **rating** you want to do 3 tasks.

1.**Insert** the new rating value in table Review table.

2.**Select** the total number of rating for the same product.
(you can get the totals of all ratings for the relevant product id and divide in to number of ratings available for the product)

3.**Update** the product table with the total average rating.